get data from column of json arrays in sqlite table
I have SQLite table with columns like this:



id
info




1
[{"a": 1, "b":2}, {"a": 3, "b":4}]


2
[{"a": 5, "b":6}, {"a": 7, "b":8}, {"a": 9, "b":10},]



I need to get table like this:



id
sum(a*b)




1
14


2
176



My best attempt looks like this, I found it in another topic
SELECT t1.id, sum((t2.value->>'$.a')*(t2.value->>'$.b'))
FROM demo AS t1
JOIN json_each((SELECT info FROM demo WHERE id = t1.id)) AS t2

but this query gives error "malformed JSON". I also tried to do it without join but result was the same error.
I don't understand, why they're malformed JSON if I do aggregation? there should be more subqueries?
How can I fix it?

The second row has a trailing comma in the array which probably won't work in old SQLite versions but your query works for me in 3.44.2 (but returns 1 | 190).

Adding a group by t1.id to your query returns the result you want with SQLite 3.44.2.

@Dogbert I use 3.44.2 too

Can you try running select sqlite_version() in your code to confirm? Because I copy pasted your data and your query and it works for me.
